# Unable to map a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, mapping, symbolic-math, markov-chains

I have this 3x3 system of equations for 2-D markov chain. I want to map the coefficients of this matrix to look like this 9x9 matrix having those zeros coefficients as well but i don't know how to proceed with it. Any help ?

```
[ 5*P11 - 2*P12 - 2*P21, 7*P12 - 5*P11 - 4*P13 - 2*P22,          9*P13 - 5*P12 - 2*P23]
[ 7*P21 - 2*P22 - 4*P31, 9*P22 - 5*P21 - 4*P23 - 4*P32, 11*P23 - 5*P22 - 5*P13 - 4*P33]
[         9*P31 - 2*P32,        11*P32 - 5*P31 - 4*P33,          8*P33 - 5*P32 - 5*P23]
```

[Coefficient Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDMD4.png)

Comment: Pxx are symbolic variables?

Comment: @Daniel It says undefined function 1P11'.
I created my symbolic variables like this.
n=2;
jmax=n+1;

P = sym(zeros((n+1),(n+1)));
for j1=1:jmax
    for j2=1:jmax
        P(j1,j2) = sym(sprintf('P%d%d', j1,j2));
    end
end

Comment: I noticed my comment was incomplete and deleted it before you answered. Currently writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coeffs` to get the coefficients.

```
syms P11 P12 P13 P21 P22 P23 P31 P32 P33
%your data
T=[ 5*P11 - 2*P12 - 2*P21, 7*P12 - 5*P11 - 4*P13 - 2*P22,          9*P13 - 5*P12 - 2*P23;...
    7*P21 - 2*P22 - 4*P31, 9*P22 - 5*P21 - 4*P23 - 4*P32, 11*P23 - 5*P22 - 5*P13 - 4*P33;...
    9*P31 - 2*P32,        11*P32 - 5*P31 - 4*P33,          8*P33 - 5*P32 - 5*P23];
%get a list of all variables. Optional, sort here if you expect another ordering.
allvars=symvar(T);

%initialize empty matix
C=zeros(numel(T),numel(allvars));
%build up coefficient matrix
for ix=1:numel(T)
    [a,b]=coeffs(T(ix));
    C(ix,ismember(allvars,b))=a;
end
```

which returns

```
>> C

C =

     5    -2     0    -2     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     7    -2     0    -4     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     9    -2     0
    -5     7    -4     0    -2     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0    -5     9    -4     0    -4     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0    -5    11    -4
     0    -5     9     0     0    -2     0     0     0
     0     0    -5     0    -5    11     0     0    -4
     0     0     0     0     0    -5     0    -5     8
```

Comment: Just a quick query.
I am trying to enter my code in this comment section but my code s not showing like yours.

Comment: `P=sym('P',[3,3])` might be a way to simplify it.

Comment: Much better.
If you notice, one of the entry (-4) in the last column  is misplaced. 
It should be in column 5.
Also, i want it be a diagonal dominant matrix.

Comment: @user3729921: I don't understand your comment. I did not use your image of the coefficient matrix as a template for ordering because it clearly does not match your data (e.g. only two coefficients for P33). It might be a case of row-major vs. column major ordering.